# Oracle number in parentheses instead of the field name

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a functionality in Oracle which permits to use a number in parentheses instead of naming a field to order a result. Example : this query order the result by the "id" column :

```
select name, id
from table
order by (2)
```

What is the name of this functionality and where can I can read documentation on it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/support/oracle/doc/10.2/server.102/b14200/queries005.htm#sthref2608).

I don't know that it has an "official" name, but "order by position" yields a good field of hits via Google.

(You also do not need to use the parens. "ORDER BY 2,1,4" works fine).

Comment: This is helpful. But I want to understand the "position" mechanism of Oracle. Ex. Can I use it in a GROUP BY ?

Comment: No, not in the GROUP BY clause - you must explicitly name each item exactly as it appears the select list.

Comment: Not that it wouldn't be handy at times ;-)